# Does Java Spring Boot applications hibernate/"go dormant" overnight

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm doing a microservice architecture with Spring boot java application.
My startups are around 16-19 seconds, so it does not look like my classpath/spring-boot application is polluted with startup stuff.

Though when I've not used a service for a while. FX. overnight, then when I use it again, it's like it has gone into some kind of hibernation, which makes the request time out.

Have anyone experienced someting similar and is there a solution ?

Comment: I am pretty sure there is no such function :) Maybe you just get a deadlock or an exception?

Comment: No, that's not a feature of Spring Boot. They don't need sleep. However depending on your environment there are plenty of possibilities. One possibility could be that GC shrinks the heap, the memory is given to some other processes, and when you make another request the memory needs to be swapped out to regrow the heap.

Comment: @Kayaman is there any config to prevent this ? :)

Comment: There's plenty you can do. *After* you make sure you understand what the underlying cause is. Check your server and see if it has any swap configured in the first place. Then verify if the swap is being used at the point when the program is presumably dormant.

Comment: @Kayaman I'm not sure how to do that, you know where i can read up on that, or do you know of any good tutorials on it, anyways thanks for the initial inputs, very handy

Comment: Server administration is quite a broad issue to address here. If you have a Linux server, you can use `free -m`, `top` and/or `ps` to find some details about the memory use.

Comment: Thanks, it's an IBMI so quite a special case. Anyways, I'll look into it, I'd suggest you writing up your comments as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there's no Spring Boot specific "hibernation" functionality, there can be plenty of things that react to long periods of inactivity. From datasources' "minimum idle" connections to the GC freeing up excess (for the time being) heap space and giving it back to the OS.

If there are other memory hungry services running on the same machine, it's possible that there's swap contention when a Java app wakes up from its slumber and decides it wants to grow its heap. You could try running `jstat` to see what kind of memory usage the VM has at different points in time. Here's an article documenting the usage https://www.cubrid.org/blog/how-to-monitor-java-garbage-collection/

It might not be a swap issue, but I'd wager it's likely somehow related to the environment, not just Java (or Spring Boot) itself.